# What are some best practices for a creating a constructor that takes a boolean isX and depending on that value would need a boolean for isY?

Tags: java

In this hypothetical problem I'm creating a class to represent Sausage which can be:
A. Fresh and Packaged
B. Fresh and Not Packaged
C. Not Fresh and Not Packaged

Note: It can't be Not Fresh and Packaged.

I'm looking for the best practice to create constructor with this in mind.

The way I tried is below, but I think there should be a better solutions.

```java
public class Sausage {
    Meat meat;
    boolean isFresh;
    boolean isPackaged;

    public Sausage(Meat meat, Boolean isFresh, Boolean isPackaged) {
        this.meat = meat;
        if (!isFresh) {
            this.isFresh = false;
            this.isPackaged = false;
        }
        else if (isPackaged) {
            this.isFresh = true;
            this.isPackaged = true;
        }
        else {
            this.isFresh = true;
            this.isPackaged = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a cleaner way to provide this functionality.

Comment: Any reason why you use the `Boolean` objects as a parameter instead of their primitive counterpart (which you use internally)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent the possible states as an enumeration type:

```java
enum SausageType {
    FreshPackaged,
    FreshUnpackaged,
    NotFresh;
}
```

Then change your constructor to take a `SausageType` instead of two `Boolean`s.

The advantage of this method is that it is not possible to call the constructor with the wrong combination of states, it is obvious to users of your class what the possible values are, and you do not need to remember to keep brittle runtime checking of arguments up to date with changing requirements.

Comment: Very good.  The OP's problem isn't really "handle all the variations of all the different boolean conditions".  It's actually "identify the 'state'".  As such, an enum is an *IDEAL* solution.

Comment: @paulsm4: whether the solution is ideal depends on how the usage is in the rest of the code would be. Since this is a theoretical question, lets assume a scenario where you get the fresh and packaged state from somewhere else (i.e. some external services). In this case you would still need a factory to convert the different flags into an enum, so it might be more appropriate to use a factory in the first place.

Comment: @second Quite true -- the general applicability of my answer would depend on what the rest of the code looks like.

Comment: second is arguing that considering "enum" as a solution might be premature, without knowing more about the application.  I can't disagree.  But babbling about "factories" is even MORE "premature", for the same reason.  I was simply afraid that the OP might be "locked in" to thinking solely about booleans and if/else blocks.  Brannan Vincent's alternate perspective - considering "state" instead of "juggling booleans" was extremely helpful.  IMHO :)

Comment: Thank you for this solution. After reading your comments, this will be the solution that I will implement. I generalized the problem, however the context is creating a library so this solution works beautifully. I wasn't familiar with enum. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems with your current approach:

1. There is a way to create write `new` object which makes no sense e.g. `new Sausage(..., false, true)` where packaged will be silently converted to `false`. This is confusing and makes code harder to understand.
2. You are mixing `Boolean` object type and `boolean` primitive type which will result in unnecessary auto-boxing. If you don't need to support `null` use `boolean`.
3. `boolean` fields probably don't need `is` prefix.

Since there are two boolean flags and 4 possibilities they can be set (`true true`, `true false`, `false true`, `false false`) but only 3 valid options perhaps named factory methods would be more suitable:

```
public class Sausage {

    public static Sasuage newFreshPackaged(Meat meat) {
      return new Sasuage(meat, true, true);
    }

    public static Sasuage newFreshNotPackaged(Meat meat) {
      return new Sasuage(meat, true, false);
    }

    public static Sasuage newNotFreshNotPackaged(Meat meat) {
      return new Sasuage(meat, false, false);
    }

    private Sausage(Meat meat, boolean fresh, boolean packaged) {
        this.meat = meat;
        this.fresh = fresh;
        this.packaged = packaged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Silently changing `isPackaged` to `false` may be a surprise to calling code.  Here, you may choose to throw an exception if the combination (not fresh, packaged) is chosen.

```
if (!isFresh && isPackaged) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't be both not fresh and packaged!");
}
this.isFresh = isFresh;
this.isPackaged = isPackaged;
```

You may also decide to use factory methods (making your constructor `private`) that enforce your requirements.  This would avoid needing an exception to be thrown.

```
public static Sausage createFreshSausage(Meat meat, boolean isPackaged) {
    return new Sausage(meat, true, isPackaged);
}

public static Sausage createNotFreshSausage(Meat meat) {
    return new Sausage(meat, false, false);
}
```

Incidentally, normally the primitive `boolean` would be used in the constructor's parameters' types, not the object wrapper `Boolean`, like your instance variables.  A `null` value here that would be allowed by `Boolean` doesn't make any sense.